# Using references in NUnit with Bamboo

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, nunit, bamboo

I have a unit test (NUnit) which refers to a resource in a Visual Studio project. The test works correctly in Visual Studio, but when I try to run it with Bamboo, our build/CI server, this error occurs:

`SetUp : System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'IOHandlerLibrary, Version=1.0.5508.26943, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

Bamboo is configured to run the DLL of the test project. It also has available in the same directory as the DLL the file which is being referenced by the resource.

Here is an example of how the resource is being accessed:

```
        string superTruss = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(IOHandlerUnitTests.Resource1.SuperTruss);
```

Comment: make sure that you are doing one or 3 of the following 
1. adding the reference to the header of the Class File `using section`
2. check if `Copy Local=true` for that assembly
3. create a `Lib or dependencies` folder and place the dll(s) there and remove the existing reference from the reference node and re-add from the new folder location

Comment: I am not 100% familiar with Bamboo NUnit test runner but first I would verify the bitness of the tested assemblies and the Bamboo unit test runner (x64 vs x86), if there is a mismatch then `BadImageFormatException` can be thrown.

Comment: Michal, I'm pretty sure that's not the problem. The project is Any CPU and its being built on the server with MSBuild 32bit, a config which is working on other projects. I verified this again!

Comment: MethodMan, 1) What do I need to add the reference to? 2) This is the case.